# Stop windows from resizing automatically?

Tags: macos, window-manager

OS X keeps hitting a pet peeve nerve that I have, and it is normally happening with internet browsers.

I'll describe two examples:

1. When using Safari, I am surfing normally on one web page. I open a
   new tab and the new tab bar shows up. The browser resizes to be
   larger by the amount of the height of the tab bar.
2. When using Google Chrome, I start a download and the download bar pops up on the
   bottom. The browser window resizes to be larger by the amount of the height of
   the download bar.

For some reason this annoys me greatly. I resize and position windows in a way that helps me focus, I guess. It's an organizational thing.

This happens for multiple reasons and in multiple applications. The above examples are just to illustrate a point.

Is there a way to disable applications in OS X from changing sizes with me dragging the window edge?